# Errors with new contracts

Tags: corda

I am trying to implement a new version of an existing contract but am running into some issues. The updates to the contract aren't to fix a bug and were implemented in a way to be backwards compatible. Current workflow was:

1- Update the state / contract

2- Ensure they work as expected

3- Create the jar file for v2

4- Remove v1 jar from all nodes and distribute v2 jar to all nodes.

5- Restart all nodes on the network

When I do this, I get the following error:

`E 02:21:57+0000 [main] cordapp.CordappProviderImpl.verifyInstalledCordapps - Contract com.p.contracts.CampContract found in attachment 916D0DE76A4CC4DEEEB200DA5A49303ACEE3F3006B45036912714CA29C02325B is not whitelisted in the network parameters. If this is a production node contact your zone operator. See https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html {}`

I tried distributing updated network-parameters, but don't think I did that correctly. I just locally ran the gradlew clean deployNodes task then uploaded the resulting network-parameters file to all nodes. When I do that and restart, it starts up fine. But then if I try to execute a flow, I get this error:

`input state requires notary "O=Notary, L=New York, C=US" which does not match the transaction notary "O=Notary, L=New York, C=US"`

Not positive what to do here. Other than the notary, I have 7 other nodes running. Is there another way to update the network parameters or am I not approaching this the correct way?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Corda ? I found 3.0 to exhibit some interesting behaviour for contract upgrades. 3.3 is looking a lot more promising for this kind of usage

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the new Contract V2 JAR file in the Network Parameters CZ Whitelist using the bootstrapper tool as per https://docs.corda.net/head/network-bootstrapper.html#updating-the-contract-whitelist-for-bootstrapped-networks

Comment: Thanks Jose. The network isn’t bootstrapped, though. Perhaps bootstrapping it locally and distributing the resultant network parameters on the actual network could work?

Comment: If the network isn't bootstrapped, are you saying it has a network map instead?

Comment: How did you generate the original network parameters, when you were using the original contract, before trying to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happened here is that when you did "clean deployNodes" you reset all the keys, so the network parameters file is now talking about a freshly created notary with different pubkey - Corda really cares about pubkeys even though it often uses X.500 names in the UI, hence the strange/confusing error message.

For re-signing a network parameters file in a *non* bootstrapped network, unfortunately in Corda 3 we don't provide a tool out of the box, as the intention is that bootstrapped networks are used for testing and testnet or the main Corda network is used for deployment. However it's only a few lines of code to make one, see how we do it here:

https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/node-api/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/internal/network/NetworkParametersCopier.kt

Hopefully that is enough for you to update the params file you have with your custom setup.